# Need to make <td> tags into external links using HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am trying to allow visitors to click on a link inside a table that uses CSS3 animation classes...I can't seem to get the DIV background image to become a link...see below HTML and CSS3...

I would like to make each `<td>` into a clickable external link...

I have tried to surround the `<td>` with an `<a>` tag...tried to put the `<a>` tag inside the `<td>` tag...

thanks for your help...

Please see this fiddle - **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/9gm74/)**

HTML:

```html
<div id="partner_holder">

<table width="75%" height="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
  <td class="showbox slideright"><div id="partner_holder_1"></div></td>
    <td class="showbox slideright"><div id="partner_holder_2"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="showbox slideright"><div id="partner_holder_3"></div></td>
    <td class="showbox slideright"><div id="partner_holder_4"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="showbox slideright"><div id="partner_holder_5"></div></td>
    <td class="showbox slideright"><div id="partner_holder_6"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#gallery_holder
{
    width:90%;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-left:15%;
    color:white;
    height:450px;
    background:none;

}

#gallery_holder_1
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:0%;
    background: url(../images/pic1.png);
    overflow:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }

.showbox {

    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
  }
  .showbox.slideright:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
  }


#gallery_holder_2
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:0%;
    background: url(../images/pic2.png);
    overflow:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

#gallery_holder_3
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:0%;
    background: url(../images/pic3.png);
    overflow:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

#gallery_holder_4
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:0%;
    background: url(../images/pic4.png);
    overflow:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

#gallery_holder_5
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:0%;
    background: url(../images/pic5.png);
    overflow:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

#gallery_holder_6
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:0%;
    background: url(../images/pic6.png);
    overflow:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any link tags at all.

Comment: Did you try <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>?

Comment: <td class="showbox slideright"><a href="www.example"><div id="partner_holder_3"></div></a></td>

Comment: Do you have to use tables? Why not pure CSS?

Comment: Yes...I would like to surround my DIV tag which has a background image with the <a> tag...when I do it makes my image disappear....

Comment: I am using the table because when I re-size the page for tablet and smart phone using fluid gridlayout it re-sizes much smoother...

Comment: I would think using fluid grids is going to be more difficult than Bootstrap (which is where I'd go with this)... 

Responsive design's intent is to serve different devices layouts tailored specifically for the type of screen. Your site's layout will generally be cut down to a single column on a smartphone for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have a link inside each  and set the following style on it you get the desired effect.  (you could set this style as part of a css class and then set each of the links to have that class to make things neater)

```
<td>
    <a style="width:100%;height:100%;display:block" href="www.yourlink.com">
        Link
    </a>
</td>
```